Fixing Transparent Line Between Div with Clip-Path and Parent Div
A thin, transparent line appears between the triangular div and its parent div when zoomed. I believe this is likely caused by anti-aliasing in the browser. If there is a way to fix this, I would appreciate it. I have also tried using SVG instead of clip-path, but the issue persists.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-red-500 h-[30rem] relative">
  <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
  <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
  <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
  <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
</div>



The line is more visible when viewed directly rather than from image btw


Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Reproduced on Chrome, but only when adding position/margin/padding on it or its parent.

@syndRain This occurs when the user zooms

wait, i will add an image

@Mr.Unknown right, but in my case even with zooming it only happen when the positioning/margin/padding are using specific units like vh. Could you also include related parent element(s)?

the parent of this <div className="bg-red-500 h-[30rem] relative"> is  with no css, plain footer

This is common when zooming in because you end up with partial pixels and the browser has to figure out what to do with them. If it's a big deal to you just move the lower div up by a pixel -mt-px.

Reproduce the problem only in Chrome, and I suspect this problem is caused by subpixel rendering inconsistencies.
Seems like the issue only happens when the div's position is moved/pushed to a y-position with subpixels (such as a previous sibling with height:80vh and a screen height that can't be divided by 1.25). This is also the reason why zooming causes this problem to appear/disappear.
For example, as shown below in Chrome the follow snippet will show the thin spaces in some specific screen size and zoom.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-[80vh] border-2 border-sky-500 m-2"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="bg-red-500 h-[30rem] relative">
    <div id="top-left" class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>



If subpixel rendering is indeed the problem in your case, this can be fixed by forcing the use of GPU rendering such as using will-change-transform as shown below. (Using a tiny rotate forces subpixel rendering as well, which is setting --tw-rotate in this case.)


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-[80vh] border-2 border-sky-500 m-2"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="bg-red-500 h-[30rem] relative will-change-transform">
    <div id="top-left" class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]"></div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)]">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>



Or, you can simply move the four triangles 1px closer to the edge as a quick solution without any performance disadvantage:


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-[80vh] border-2 border-sky-500 m-2"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="bg-red-500 h-[30rem] relative">
    <div id="top-left" class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)] top-px">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-inherit absolute transform -translate-y-full right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)] top-px">
    </div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 [clip-path:polygon(0%0%,100%100%,0%100%)] bottom-[-1px]"></div>
    <div class="w-1/2 h-10 md:h-20 bg-white absolute bottom-0 right-0 [clip-path:polygon(100%0%,100%100%,0%100%)] bottom-[-1px]">
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>



Or, just use clip-path or SVG to draw the same shape instead of using transform:


.clipped {
  height: calc(100% + var(--h));
  top: calc(-1 * var(--h));
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% var(--h), 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--h)), 50% 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--h)));
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="h-[80vh] border-2 border-sky-500 m-2"></div>
<footer>
  <div class="h-[30rem] relative">
    <div class="clipped bg-red-500 relative [--h:2.5rem] md:[--h:5rem]"></div>
  </div>
</footer>



